# In Flutter, how to use FittedBox to resize Text inside of a Row?

Tags: layout, flutter

I have a row, with an icon at each side, and then a text with an icon in the middle:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
      Icon(Icons.account_box),
      Text("Some Text Here ", maxLines: 1), // ➜ This is the text.
      Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
      Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
    ],
  );
}
```

When the text gets big enough to fill the whole space, I want a `FittedBox` to make is smaller. So I tried this:

```
      FittedBox(child: Text("Some Text Here. More. More. More. More. More. More. More. More. ", maxLines: 1)),
```

It doesn't work (it overflows). I believe the problem is that `Row` doesn't tell `FittedBox` the maximum size it could have. I have thought about using `FittedBox` with `Expanded`, `IntrinsicWidth`, `UnconstrainedBox`, `Flexible` and `Align`, to no avail.

How can I solve this?

**Update:** I wrote an article which would have helped me solve this problem: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-the-advanced-layout-rule-even-beginners-must-know-edc9516d1a2

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For what I understand you need to fit the text inside of the row, according to text length.

Working Code:

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.account_box),
          Flexible(
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              child: Text(
                "  Text HereSome Text Here Text HereSomext HereSome TText HereSome Text HereSome Text HereSome Text HereSome Text HereSome TText HereSome Text HereSome Text HereSome",
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
  ],
);
```

**Output, long text:**

[image]

**Output, short text:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you only want to use `FittedBox` to fit the text in same row ? Alternatively, if you need to fit or wrap the text in single row, you need to wrap the `Text` inside `Flexible` widget which basically fits the child tightly.

I recreated your case and was able to achieve below:

[image]

Code for above is:

```
Row(
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
        Icon(Icons.account_box),
        Flexible(
        child:
        Text("Some Text Here and here and here and here and more and more and more and more and more and more ", maxLines: 1)), // ➜ This is the text.
        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
        Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      ],
      )
```

Since, you have set `maxLines` to be 1, it's going to take your original text `Some text here` and will display it properly without overflow. If you add more text to it, it's not going to expand the row and will prevent overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem was just using FittedBox when the text got too big to fix the space, and I'm going with anmol.majhail's solution.